# How can I make the image above the text when changing screen size

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

```css
.service1{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 39% 61%;
}
.s-info{
    padding: 20% 10% 0 10%;
    background-color: #072645;
    color: white;
}
.s-info h1{
    font-size: 2rem;
}
/* font-size:1rem for width 300px */
.s-info p{
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.s-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 646px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
       <div class="service1">
        <div class="s1 s-info">
          <div class="line"></div>
          <h1>UX/UI Design</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur a accusantium commodi ex
            minima nulla voluptate autem!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            a accusantium commodi ex minima nulla voluptate autem!
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum,
            inventore nobis!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur a
            accusantium commodi ex minima nulla voluptate autem! Voluptate alias
            esse cumque?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="s-img">
          <img
            src="https://s3-alpha-sig.figma.com/img/bcb7/a1c5/6db72a2f9cd55704e0e140a6eb63d3b5?Expires=1646006400&Signature=caVOH5cjcYrUaZ3KO10XI1~HwKtOMJJ4BI4ZvrXxJGhblSsO4e0~7imCTNl39XAeswii-n3zx7yPcgJERp3-h-d4tE5YgvBQArJKFBKsG1rq3T43NYQcgMpIWR0apgqfWGr8xA15DAcwQLt6EXAdWCXREiWJbQf~yLBpelTqX4okY1Ib8T3~~4tjJB77btzPAA8YifULxwptCytIzVKDOXLHS6dGRXqLjkuhgQeH6sL0~BRfFVbXkW7KeYVaDxM-ZcFm3XMycaVu0zcLDXBlwFrYK4c~~eletJfTpceREFmET4HF-AVMu3Mbe6L8F7bpNjysxpQKH2aS8nswj0ykDA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAINTVSUGEWH5XD5UA"
            alt=""
            srcset=""
          />
        </div>
      </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

I have used css grid to make this structure.
I can't figure out how to stack image above text after a particular screen size, I thought about media query but couldn't think through it.
Please help!
Its a simple grid with 2 columns. I want to know if there is a way that when the screen size shrinks image(right side component/ 2nd item) comes above and text comes below it.
[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide some code (HTML and CSS at a minimum) that reproduces the issue you are having. A picture is great and all, but doesn't tell us how far you've gotten.

Comment: Its a simple grid with 2 columns. I want to know if there is a way that when the screen size shrinks image(right side component/ 2nd item) comes above and text comes below it.

Comment: Part of the mission of Stack Overflow is to help lots of people with the same problem. A picture is not searchable. Nor are comments. Also, if people are looking for how to do something specific to CSS Grid, they may come across this question, but there is no CSS grid code to refer to, for comparison. So please, [edit] your question with further clarification, and any attempts and research you've done. [ask] contains many tips on how to ask questions that are less likely to be downvoted or closed.

Comment: Okay thanks I will go through it and please check it again if you could help me I have added the code

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as usual, is media queries. For grids, it's changing the template columns and rows so that things are stacked as you want them.

Here I've set the breakpoint at 800px so that it would stack in Stack Overflow's normal design, but maybe not at full page.

*(I also changed the way your image was displayed so that it never appears distorted; that was a personal decision. Just remove `aspect-ratio` and uncomment your height to get it back to normal).*

```css
.service1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 39% 61%;
}

.s-info {
  padding: 20% 10% 0 10%;
  background-color: #072645;
  color: white;
}

.s-info h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}


/* font-size:1rem for width 300px */

.s-info p {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.s-img img {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 646px;*/
  aspect-ratio: 1.977808599167822;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .service1 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .s-info {
    padding: 0 10%;
    grid-row: 2/2;
    grid-column: 1/1;
  }
  .s-img {
    grid-row: 1/1;
    grid-column: 1/1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="service1">
    <div class="s1 s-info">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <h1>UX/UI Design</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur a accusantium commodi ex minima nulla voluptate autem!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur a accusantium commodi ex minima nulla voluptate autem!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, inventore nobis!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur a accusantium commodi ex minima nulla voluptate autem! Voluptate alias esse cumque?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="s-img">
      <img src="https://s3-alpha-sig.figma.com/img/bcb7/a1c5/6db72a2f9cd55704e0e140a6eb63d3b5?Expires=1646006400&Signature=caVOH5cjcYrUaZ3KO10XI1~HwKtOMJJ4BI4ZvrXxJGhblSsO4e0~7imCTNl39XAeswii-n3zx7yPcgJERp3-h-d4tE5YgvBQArJKFBKsG1rq3T43NYQcgMpIWR0apgqfWGr8xA15DAcwQLt6EXAdWCXREiWJbQf~yLBpelTqX4okY1Ib8T3~~4tjJB77btzPAA8YifULxwptCytIzVKDOXLHS6dGRXqLjkuhgQeH6sL0~BRfFVbXkW7KeYVaDxM-ZcFm3XMycaVu0zcLDXBlwFrYK4c~~eletJfTpceREFmET4HF-AVMu3Mbe6L8F7bpNjysxpQKH2aS8nswj0ykDA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAINTVSUGEWH5XD5UA"
        alt="" srcset="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! it makes much more sense now and also for additional aspect ratio tip much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's a little confusing. You can design any responsive page you want with media queries. I gave `float none` for make the box above the text. You can run code snippet with full page for test it.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .box {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    float: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .box p {
    margin-top: 20%;
  }
  .container {
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .container span p {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .box {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 450px;
    height: 250px;
    float: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .box p {
    margin-top: 20%;
  }
  .container {
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: block;
    width: 550px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .container span p {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .box {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 550px;
    height: 350px;
    float: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .box p {
    margin-top: 20%;
  }
  .container {
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: block;
    width: 650px;
    height: 550px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .container span p {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .box {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 660px;
    height: 450px;
    float: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .box p {
    margin-top: 20%;
  }
  .container {
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: block;
    width: 750px;
    height: 650px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .container span p {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .box {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
  }

  .box p {
    margin-top: 40%;
  }

  .container {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 750px;
    height: 270px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .container span p {
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="box">
            <p>Box1</p>
        </div>
        <span>
            <p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda saepe ad
                quibusdam optio? Nisi nostrum necessitatibus, veritatis vitae excepturi autem officia nulla quaerat
                mollitia
                dolorem quas ipsum in molestiae nesciunt!
                Aspernatur consequuntur rem, tenetur est ab beatae, id sunt optio illum ipsum, ut adipisci libero
                dolores
            </p>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="box">
            <p>Box2</p>
        </div>
        <span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda saepe ad
                quibusdam optio? Nisi nostrum necessitatibus, veritatis vitae excepturi autem officia nulla quaerat
                mollitia
                dolorem quas ipsum in molestiae nesciunt!
                Aspernatur consequuntur rem, tenetur est ab beatae, id sunt optio illum ipsum, ut adipisci libero
                dolores
            </p>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="box">
            <p>Box3</p>
        </div>
        <span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda saepe ad
                quibusdam optio? Nisi nostrum necessitatibus, veritatis vitae excepturi autem officia nulla quaerat
                mollitia
                dolorem quas ipsum in molestiae nesciunt!
                Aspernatur consequuntur rem, tenetur est ab beatae, id sunt optio illum ipsum, ut adipisci libero
                dolores
            </p>
        </span>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, mostly because I'm not sure what the question is. But the OP does mention CSS Grid, and this answer does not use CSS Grid, so it fails on that count, anyway. I think you should concentrate on answering well-asked questions, and leave these poorly-asked questions alone (as advised in [answer]).

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your suggestions. I will consider